# Super big size sprite sheet to load in android - outofmemoryerror

Tags: java, android, sprite, out-of-memory

My question is what would be the best possible solution or work around for my problem?

This is my problem. I am doing a 2d android game from a flash game. I have a png image with dimension 8000 x 4800. It is a sprite sheet with 10 columns and 10 rows, each frame has 800 x 480 dimension. I know it is super big size for the sprite sheet but because the flash game is super animated and has good graphics, we just exported each action/scene to png sequence to retain the animation and the quality of the graphics and to avoid the calculation of the animation.

If I load the picture in android, I got the outofmemoryerror. I think it is because of the image size. I got 4 more image with the same dimension to load on the same screen. Please help me. What would be the best possible solution or work around for this.

Comment: 8400x4800 = 38.4 Megapixels times 4 bytes per pixel = roughly 154MB, assuming no other overhead. I know desktop PC's that may cough on this... not to mention that most graphics hardware has limits on how big a bitmap/texture can be. This design will get you into trouble.

Comment: @Durandal What do you think would be the best work around for this? Btw thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sale down the image before display the same.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.

Check the topic under Loading Scaled Down version in memory.

Also you should recycle bitmaps when not in use. Like load bitmaps in onResume() and in onPause() recycle bitmaps.

```
   bitmap.recycle()
```

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

The talk in the video is about memory management.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try your suggestion.